# How to do a class method that is not a function?

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Library {
    constructor(a){
    this.total = a;
    }
            
        add(...a){
            for (const arg of a) {
                  this.total += arg;
            }
            return this;
        }
        
        subtract(...b){
            for (const args of b) {
              this.total -= b;
            }
            return this;
            }
            
   
        result() {
            console.log(this.total);
            return this.total
            }
            
       
            


}

    $ = new Library(10); // inititliaize the base as 10

// var x = $.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result;    
// x should be 10+3+5+5+10-10 or basically 23
// var y = $.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10,3,5).result to return 15
```

The problem requires the exact line.

```
var x = $.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result;
```

The problem requires to chain a method "result" that is not a function I tried

```
  result = function(){
    return this.total;
  };
```

Is there a way to return a value in a class without using a function?

Comment: Yes, a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Answer (score 5):

#### Option 1:

You can achieve the expected line format using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
class Library {
  #total;
  constructor(a){
    this.#total = a;
  }
            
  add(...a) {
    for (const arg of a) {
      this.#total += arg;
    }
    return this;
  }
        
  subtract(...b){
    for (const arg of b) {
      this.#total -= arg;
    }
    return this;
  }
 
  get result() {
    console.log(this.#total);
    return this.#total
  }
}

const $ = new Library(10);
console.log($.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result);
```

Technically, it's a function call, but you omit the parenthesis.

#### Option 2:

You can store the result after each calculation:

```js
class Library {
  #total;
  constructor(a){
    this.#total = a;
    this.result = this.#total;
  }
            
  add(...a) {
    for (const arg of a) {
      this.#total += arg;
    }
    this.result = this.#total;
    return this;
  }
        
  subtract(...b){
    for (const arg of b) {
      this.#total -= arg;
    }
    this.result = this.#total;
    return this;
  }
}

const $ = new Library(10);
console.log($.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result);
```

Comment: Option 3: just rename `.total` to `.result`

Comment: @Bergi In this simplified example, yes, but I would separate these two values in a more complex class. In Typescript I would use `private` `total` and `public` `result`.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is the @property decorator which is really helpul to avoid to call a function and just return the value of the property.

in that case in JS you need to use the **get** which binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

```
get result() {
  return this.total
}
```

Comment: "in python" ... how is that at all relevant?

Comment: I just put it like a reference, I work with different programming languages and in some cases I like to use some reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to complicate this, when the obvious answer is to make use of a public class field named result.

```js
class Library {
    result;
    
    constructor(a) {
        this.result = a;
    }
         
    add(...a){
        for (const arg of a) {
          this.result += arg;
        }
        return this;
    }  
    subtract(...b){
        for (const arg of b) {
           this.result -= arg;
        }
        return this;
    }
}

$ = new Library(0);
var x = $.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That is the OP's code, and not relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes.  Of course with only one argument, as per the question the code did generate the right answer, but would not have if there'd been more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a more interesting case - getting result only on demand and memoize it.

I often add lazy calculations/data transforms to my apps to avoid a high load initially and don't do anything if the data isn't requested.

In this particular case it's not very obvious, even slower, just to show a principle.

```js
class Library {
  #total;
  #adds = [];
  #subtracts = [];
  constructor(a = 0){
    this.#total = a;
  }
            
  add(...a) {
    this.#adds.push(...a);
    return this;
  }
        
  subtract(...b){
    this.#subtracts.push(...b);
    return this;
  }
 
  get result() {
    this.#adds.forEach(a => this.#total+=a);
    this.#subtracts.forEach(s => this.#total-=s);
    this.#adds.length = this.#subtracts.length = 0;
    return this.#total;
  }
}

const $ = new Library(10);
console.log($.add(3,5).add(5,10).subtract(10).result);
```